# Why Windows.UI.Composition AnimationController.Progress always return zero?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm trying to read the animation [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.animationcontroller.progress?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_AnimationController_Progress) property in the [Windows.UI.Composition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition?view=winrt-19041) using the following command:

```
double progress = _target.TryGetAnimationController("Offset")?.Progress ?? double.NaN;
```

The animation of the property "Offset" on _target object runs correctly, but the progress property is **always zero** during the animation that runs over 10 seconds.

Has anyone used this property?

**Additional information**

I'm using this Microsoft sample as base code for test:
https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/tree/master/Demos/Reference%20Demos/Animations_KeyFrame/Animate_Visual_Position

I added a timer callback to read the progress:

```
    private void timerCallback(object state)
    {
       double progress = _target.TryGetAnimationController("Offset")?.Progress ?? double.NaN;
       Debug.WriteLine(progress.ToString());
    }
```

The timer is enabled in the "Animate_Click" event after init the animation.

Comment: Could you try to show the complete code, I could not reproduce this, and the better way is share us code sample that will better for testing.

Comment: Hello @NicoZhu-MSFT, I added more information about the code in the question. Thanks for helping

Comment: I could reproduce this behavior, but I'm not sure if it is by-design, I need do more testing for this, and you could also post issue report in `WindowsCompositionSamples` [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/issues).

Comment: I added a issue in the samples repository: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/issues/346

Comment: Good, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

AnimationController.Progress property always return zero while running a KeyFrameAnimation is by design as answered [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/issues/346).

Using a CompositionScopeBatch and creating the animation in sub paths is possible to set events at specific points, this solve my problem.